# object kafka010 is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i am trying to consume messages from secured kafka cluster with SSL enabled.
now i have added dependencies for my scala 2.13.6 version.

```
name := "realtime-spark-streaming"

version := "0.1"
resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
resolvers += "Public Maven Repository" at "https://repository.***.com/content/repositories/pangaea_releases"

resolvers += "Nexus Repository" at "https://repository.***.com/content/repositories/pangaea_releases/"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.2.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "3.2.0" % "2.1.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.12"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "6.1.0-ccs"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
```

my consumer app looks like this

```
package main.scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
object APP extends App {
  println("Hello, World!")

  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
  "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
  "ssl.truststore.location" -> "/some-directory/kafka.client.truststore.jks",
  "ssl.truststore.password" -> "test1234",
  "ssl.keystore.location" -> "/some-directory/kafka.client.keystore.jks",
  "ssl.keystore.password" -> "test1234",
  "ssl.key.password" -> "test1234"
  )



  val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    streamingContext,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

  stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
}
```

when i build the package its not showing any dependency mismatch error , but when i run my kafka import is not resolving..
i am getting error

```
object kafka010 is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
```

also i am not sure what is the relative path to give for truststore and keystore if my cert is in resource directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you have `% "2.1.3"`... SBT should be giving you an error saying that that wasn't downloaded.

> scala 2.13.6

Then you cannot use `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_*2.11*`. You'd need to use `_2.13` (which only exists for Spark 2.3.0). You can use the `%%` symbol to make sure this is always the case

```
val sparkVersion = "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
```

Also, don't manually add `kafka-clients`, and you should add `provided` to `spark-core`